# hHide animation after form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, css-animations

I have an animation inside a `div` that is always running, but it's hidden by default. I unhide it on form `submit`, but not sure how to hide it back when the page changed. This means that if the user presses the `back` button on their browser and the page is still cached (so it doesn't reload), the animation is still shown. How can I fix this? The form is not using `AJAX`.

HTML:

```
<div id="loader" class="hidden">
    <div id="loop" class="center"></div>
    <div id="plane-wrapper" class="center">
        <div id="bike" class="centerPlane"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#search_form').submit(function(){
    $('#loader').show();
});
```

I tried adding

```
$(document).on( "pagechange", function() {
    ('#loader').hide();
});
```

but this didn't solve anything.

Comment: if the page is not using ajax then it is fully refreshed? if so your animation should be hidden as by default. If you can put a jsfiddle it will be easier to help you

Comment: It is hidden by default, but after pressing `submit`, the animation is shows, and if the user goes back after being redirected by the form submission (without reloading the page, just quickly pressing back and getting the previous page from cache), the animation is still there.

Comment: problem not in jquery but in page caching, right?

Comment: @kpblc Well jQuery might have a way of detecting when a page is being retrieved from the cache, or when a page is being redisplayed, or more likely a function that detects that the submit button finished its execution and a new page is going to be displayed after the redirect. A hook right before the redirect or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="clickme">
Click here
</div>
<img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123">


$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  // With the element initially hidden, we can show it slowly:
  $( "#book" ).show( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

use callback - example from http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: Thanks, but the animation should complete when the page has finished loading. If I add `$('#loader').hide()` in the callback, it hides the animation before.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use **document.ready** function replace with your **page change** function on your previous page.

`$(document).ready(function() {
('#loader').hide();
});`

thanks

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't have any effect. I don't think the `$(document).ready()` is called if the page is not reloaded